# Why this error: ERROR 1022 (23000): Can't write; duplicate key in table 'C:\WINDOWS\SERVIC~1\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\#sql484c_181_2a'

Tags: mysql

`integers` is a table which holds integers from 0 and larger.

```
SELECT i, floor(rand()*4)+1 r 
FROM integers 
WHERE i<=10
```

this query produces two columns, `i` and `r` with (i.e.) next result:

```
+----+---+
| i  | r |
+----+---+
|  0 | 3 |
|  1 | 1 |
|  2 | 1 |
|  3 | 3 |
|  4 | 4 |
|  5 | 4 |
|  6 | 1 |
|  7 | 1 |
|  8 | 4 |
|  9 | 2 |
| 10 | 2 |
+----+---+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, when i do this:

```
SELECT r, count(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT i, floor(rand()*4)+1 r 
  FROM integers 
  WHERE i<=10) x 
GROUP BY x.r;
```

I am getting:

```
ERROR 1022 (23000): Can't write; duplicate key in table 'C:\WINDOWS\SERVIC~1\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\#sql484c_181_2c'
```

expected was:

| r | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

EDIT:
Version of MySQL is 8.0.23

The table `integers` is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `integers` (
  `i` int NOT NULL,
  `t1` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`i`),
  KEY `integers_t1` (`t1`),
  KEY `even` (((`i` % 2)))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

There are 2621442 records in that table, and the minimum and maximum value for i are 0 and 2621450.

And finally diskspace:

| disk | free |
| --- | --- |
| C | 118Gb |
| D | 586Gb |

The datadir for MySQL is on the D-drive.

EDIT2:

When doing the same on MariaDB, version 10.5.9-MariaDB, also on Windows, there is no error, and the expected result is returned.

EDIT3:

A [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=562a2b953e996a035716c2ccdf1e05b8) showing the problem.

EDIT4:

I did create a bug report, see: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103632

This problem was also reproducible on "Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"

Comment: Wierd. You're obvs on Windows. What version of MySQL do you use?  What's the definition of the `integers` table and how many rows does it hold? Are you running out of disk space? Please [edit] your question.